# How to animate object using bezier path?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cgpoint, cakeyframeanimation

[image]

Here is my code to draw dashed line

```
func drawLine() {

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.bounds = viewDraw.bounds
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: viewDraw.bounds.width/2, y: viewDraw.bounds.height/2)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = ColorConstants.ThemeColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round // Updated in swift 4.2
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [10]

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: viewDraw.bounds, cornerRadius: viewDraw.bounds.size.height/2)
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    viewDraw.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.duration = 1
    shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")
}
```

Now as per my screenshot I want to animate blue dot to red dot within that dashed line infinite time. When blue dot reaches red dot then it will start again with blue dot points.

**Note: This whole screen is dynamic so, Line draw is also dynamic according to screen height**

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there

Now you have to add animation using `CAKeyframeAnimation` which has property `path` where you can pass the path where you want to animate

here is working sample code

```
func drawLine() {

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.bounds = self.view.bounds
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.height/2)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round // Updated in swift 4.2
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [10]

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.view.bounds, cornerRadius: self.view.bounds.size.height/2)
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    let animation1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation1.fromValue = 0
    animation1.duration = 1
    shapeLayer.add(animation1, forKey: "MyAnimation")

    // Create  squareView and add animation 
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CALayer.position))
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
    animation.path = path.cgPath

    let squareView = UIView()

   // Don't worry about x,y and width and height it will not affect the animation 
    squareView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    squareView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    view.addSubview(squareView)
    // You can also pass any unique string value for key
    squareView.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)

}
```

You can see this tutorial for more help http://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two/

Comment: Ok I have done it erlier, There is a issue of frames that's why animation is not working as expected

Comment: I don't want full animation of bezier path, I want animation of blue dot to red dot, not 360 degree